# Dynamic type with permutation in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'd like to create dynamic types excluding duplicates. This is what I have right now:

```js
type Currency = 'CAD' | 'USD' | 'EUR';
type CurrencyQuote = `${Currency}x${Currency}`; // returns:  "CADxUSD" | "USDxCAD" | "CADxCAD" | "CADxEUR" | "USDxUSD" | "USDxEUR" | "EURxCAD" | "EURxUSD" | "EURxEUR"
```

How could I exclude the ones that are duplicated, like `USD|USD`, `CAD|CAD` and `EUR|EUR`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We could use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) which maps over the elements in `Currency` and constructs the *template string literal* consisting of the current element `K` and `Exclude<Currency, K>`.

Since the mapped type returns an object with the currencies as properties, we need to index this type with `Currency` to get the union of the types of all keys.

```
type CurrencyQuote = {
    [K in Currency]: `${K}x${Exclude<Currency, K>}`
}[Currency]

// type CurrencyQuote = 
//   | "CADxUSD" 
//   | "CADxEUR"
//   | "USDxCAD" 
//   | "USDxEUR" 
//   | "EURxCAD" 
//   | "EURxUSD"
```

You might want a reusable utility type to do this.

```
type ConcatWithoutDupes<T extends string> = {
    [K in T]: `${K}x${Exclude<T, K>}`
}[T]

type CurrencyQuote = ConcatWithoutDupes<Currency>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgrgJwRAdgYxFAvFA5DAQQBFcoAfPAVQGUTy8BRSgJVwG4AoD0SWRZdCACKcAPbBoOAN4cocqAG0A0lACWKPklQYAugC4oAAwAkUpQF8AHqYaW0AGzgATCAB54WwQBooSgHzmhhzmCh4CulwA9JFQPNBh2sJiEthQHNHyFABEhESWNERZaRly2bmWTMxZ6TGlUFkFlrlFNZn1jZUtJfRZlU3EXbU9fQXV3ODxougAhsAA6qrAABaicMBEcJAAzq4AKlAQlhIoTltQW8AI6gDmfqky8ooq6lC7+kamFtZStg7ObrsfP5AsEFG8uHFNOEkuIIABGVIwKZoWYLZardabCA7BKCPxAA)

Answer (score 0):

You could make a *distributive mapped type* (as coined in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)) where you make a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) for each value `K` in `Currency` corresponding to just the values you want that begin with that value, and then use an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) to turn that into the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) you want:

```
type CurrencyQuote = { [K in Currency]: `${K}x${Exclude<Currency, K>}` }[Currency];
// type CurrencyQuote = "CADxUSD" | "CADxEUR" | "USDxCAD" |
//   "USDxEUR" | "EURxCAD" | "EURxUSD"
```

Looks good.  Note how [the `Exclude<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) is used to produce "everything in `Currency` that is not `K`" and avoid the duplication.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgrgJwRAdgYxFAvFA5DAQQBFcoAfPAVQGUTy8BRSgJVwG4AoD0SWRZdCACKcAPbBoOAN5QA2gGkoASxR8kqDAF0AXFAAGAEinyAvgA8jDM2gA2cACYQAPPHWCANFHkA+E3qgmsq4CWpwA9GFQPNDBGsJiEthQAESERGY0RMn0qcRmTMzZFMmZZmlFKaUFFckFZcQ1dZnJXBxAA)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, create the union of dupes by [distributing them](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) then exclude those explicitly:

```
type Dupes = Currency extends infer C extends string ? C extends C ? `${C}x${C}` : never : never;

type CurrencyQuote = Exclude<`${Currency}x${Currency}`, Dupes>;
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mx8Vxm)